# Statistical analysis of distributed values in Java

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, dataset

I am writing a program in Java that outputs a `List<Double>` of distances that roughly follow a bell curve distribution. From this data, I need to generate two values A and B that follow the distribution at a particular standard deviation from the mean X, one above the mean and one below the mean. The distribution may not be symmetrical but I am content to assume that it is for my purposes. These values A and B would be better than my current method of taking the min and max of the dataset, which is very vulnerable to be skewed by random outliers, and so is not always representative of a specific probability from the distribution. How would I generate these values, A and B? Should I be asking this on a different stack exchange? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you explain *why* you "need to generate two values A and B that follow the distribution at a particular standard deviation from the mean X"?  What do you hope these values would represent?  How do you plan to interpret or use them?  *Which* mean and standard deviation do you intend to use: those of the data or those of the underlying distribution generating the data?  How might this be related to "taking the min and max of the dataset"?

Answer (score 1):

"I am writing a program in Java that outputs a List of distances that roughly follow a bell curve distribution"

I assume this is your given sample which follows any distribution. From this list, I would create an empirical CDF which is

Cdf(x) number of items less than x/ total number of items

Once you got your CDF then you could randomly pick two probably numbers:  first one is  pA, between 0 and 0.5 for point A and then next  random number pB between 0.5 and 1 for point B.

Once you have these two probably numbers pA and pB, u could find associated real sample in your sample distribution A and B.